# How to divide read/write database setting in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, setting

This is recommended regulation for database divide setting in Laravel.

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
                  'host' => '192.168.1.1',
              ],
   'write' => [
                  'host' => '196.168.1.2'
              ],
      'sticky'    => true,
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
      'database'  => 'database',
      'username'  => 'root',
      'password'  => '',
      'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
      'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      'prefix'    => '',
  ],
```

But if I want to use different access information as DB_NAME, USER_ID, PASS etc to each read/write databases, then how could I make it?  Thank you.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#using-multiple-database-connections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two connections then specify the connection with Eloquent using the on method:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
'mysql2' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST2', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT2', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE2', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME2', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD2', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET2', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

```
User::on('mysql2')->where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

Or using Query Builder:

```
DB::connection('mysql2')->table('users')->where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. @leyduana. :)
By the way, how to make query that read data from A table and join with existing B table data group by id?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare another db conecction like this:

```
'mysql' => [
    'read' => [
                  'host' => '192.168.1.1',
              ],
   'write' => [
                  'host' => '192.168.1.1'
              ],
      'sticky'    => true,
      'driver'    => 'mysql',
      'database'  => 'database',
      'username'  => 'root',
      'password'  => '',
      'charset'   => 'utf8mb4',
      'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
      'prefix'    => '',
], 

'writecon' => [
    'read' => [
        'host' => '196.168.1.2',
    ],
    'write' => [
        'host' => '196.168.1.2'
    ],
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'port' => env('DB2_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB2_DATABASE', 'db2'),
    'username' => env('DB2_USERNAME', 'somename'),
    'password' => env('DB2_PASSWORD', 'somepass'),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

Then in your .env add:

```
DB2_PORT=3306
DB2_DATABASE=db2
DB2_USERNAME=somename
DB2_PASSWORD=somepass
```

And you can use it like this:

```php
$someModel->setConnection('writecon');
$someModel->save();
```

not tested but you can try it.